# Explicitly define $guarded=['id'] to prevent accidental insert?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Say I'd like to apply the following logic to all my Model class:

> All Model class with auto incremental id should have `protected $guarded = ['id']`

So that I can't accidentally insert incremental id myself.

Does it makes sense in Laravel 5?
Do I have other ways to achieve it beside setting `protected $guarded = ['id']` in each Model class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, it still makes sense to do so. While ID is not fillable by default, it can be still overwritten when modified directly with **$model->id = $id**;

A better way is to define a base class for all your models and set the **$guarded** property there. This way you only need to do this once.

```
//Model.php
<?php namespace Your\Model\Namespace;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model as Eloquent;

class Model extends Eloquent {
  protected $guarded = ['id'];
}


//SomeModel.php
<?php namespace Your\Model\Namespace;

class SomeModel extends Model {}
```

Comment: You gave me inspiration in namespacing. I never really cared where they `extends` the class.

Comment: And this answer just killed another bird: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31915138/whats-the-proper-way-to-apply-some-logic-to-all-model-class-in-laravel-5

Comment: Don't we have to put protected $guarded = ['*','id']; instead of just id as the Model class already have a guarded used ? (L5.1)

Answer (score 14):

If you follow the accepted answer, you can **still** manually set the `id`, and actually, I would actually say that answer makes your application's security worse.

Laravel already makes everything guarded by default:

`protected $guarded = ['*'];`

As a result, there's no need to specify the `id` when it's **already** guarded. When you override that property, you are telling Laravel, "Actually, don't guard everything. Only guard the properties that I specify." So essentially, you are unguarding other properties.

Also, if you are manually going to assign properties like this:

```
$model = new Model;
$model->id = 1;
$model->name = 'Example';
$model->save();
```

The `$guarded` / `$fillable` properties never kick in. They kick in when you use methods like `create`, `update`, `fill`, etc.

Comment: Exactly, I was the one asking in Laracast, and just came here to clarify that the selected is incorrect.